# Duke Nukem Forever stools

Tags: duke-nukem-forever

I am getting stuck in Duke Nukem Forever - falling off the stools in the Lady Killer (part 2).
Any tips on this?

Answer (score 1):

The stools are used as spring-boards that propel you up into the air. Use the momentum the stools give you to reach new places. Jump onto them and keep moving towards the place where you want to land. You are not supposed to stand on them.